# Live search with AJAX in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, livesearch

I'm fairly new to programming with ruby . I'm trying to create a  Livesearch  with AJAX, but is giving me headaches. The basic idea is that when a user creates a node, can be stored in the same: information of the user who created it , the parent node , etc. For this I did a  live search  where the user enters the ID of the parent node and the user data that corresponds to that node automatically appear . Then, in the same view, I want to create the node. So far I have the following code, which I'm not doing work.

I want something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [subeimagenes.com](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/join-1369789.png))</sub>

Problems:

1. AJAX not working , I'm sure I 'm forgetting something important
2. Do not know how to pass the value " parent_id " (u.id in _users.html.erb, result of " live search ") to create the node.

nodes_controller.rb

```
def new
@node = Node.new   
end

def search
@node = Node.new  
@parent = Node.search(params[:search]).where(:ocuped => true)

if not @users.nil?
  if @users.count == 1
    @node_incomplete = @users.nodes.where(" sons < ? AND ocuped = ?",2,true).first
  else
    @node_incomplete = @users.first.nodes.where(" sons < ? AND ocuped = ?",2,true).first
  end
  @son_of_incompleted_node = @node_incomplete.children
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

end

search.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @node, :id => "users_search" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search, :value => params[:search], :autocomplete => 'off' %>
  <div id='users'>
      <%= render 'users' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ocuped, :value => true %>
  <%= f.text_field :custom_node_name %>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service,{}, true,false %>
  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "button postfix" %>
<% end %>
```

_users.html.erb

```
<% if not @parent.nil? %>
<% @parent.each do |u| %>
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="img-simple" style = "text-align: center; background-image: url('<%= u.user.profile_img %>')"></li>
            <li style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><h6><%= u.user.name %></h6><p><%= u.user.email %></p></li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

node.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  self.where('id = ? ', search.to_i)
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
  $("#users_search input").keyup(function() {
  $.get($("#users_search").attr("action"), $("#users_search").serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
   });
 });
```

nodes.js.cofee

```
jQuery ->

# Ajax search on keyup
$('#users_search input').keyup( ->
  $.get($("#users_search").attr("action"), $("#users_search").serialize(), null, 'script')
false
)
```

views/nodes/search.js.erb

```
$('#users').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("users")) %>');
```